# How integrate with respect to a variable affect the whole expression

Tags: integration

I have spent some time to solve this equation and I don't know how to solve it:
$$\int_0^t e^{-rs}dk_s ,$$
where r is constant. I was thinking the result would be $e^{-rs}k_s $. But should the exponential term affect too?

Ultimately, I want to take the derivative of the above expression with respect to t. Seems like the answer is $e^{-rt}dk_t$. Could anyone please explain how to arrive at the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you know what $dk_s$ means. If not, sit down and recall the definition and how to obtain $ds$ from $dk_s$. If you know this, you can easily solve the integral.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, there is no definition about $dk_s$, so I can't find a way to restate $dk_s$ in terms of $ds$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write $k(s)$ instead of $k_s$. Using "physicists notation", $$\frac{dk(s)}{ds}=k'(s) \Longleftrightarrow dk(s)=k'(s)ds.$$ So you have to calculate $$\int_0^t e^{-rs}dk(s)=\int_0^te^{-rs}k'(s)ds.$$ Using the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, this is $F(t)-F(0)$ where $F$ is a primitive function for the integrand. Thus, differentiating w.r.t. $t$ should give back the integrand, i.e. $e^{-rt}k'(t).$

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Comment: You're welcome.